# Launching activity from Fragment, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin/Android development and I'm making an app to display quizzes. Recently I decided to begin using fragments. On my MainActivity which has three fragments, I'd like one to have a method of clicking a subject and being taken to that particular quiz activity.

Note, there is only one quiz activity, but the intents pass a variable to display the relevant data for the quiz.

I had correctly implemented this when this page was not a fragment but struggling to find a solution this time.

Subject Fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.example.financialapp.InformationPage
import com.example.financialapp.databinding.FragmentModuleBinding
import android.content.Intent

class ModuleFragment : Fragment(com.quizapp.R.layout.fragment_module) {
    private var _binding: FragmentModuleBinding ? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentModuleBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val subjectOne = binding.tvEnglish
        subjectOne.setOnClickListener {
            sendIntent(0)
        }

        val subjectTwo = binding.tvGeography
        subjectOne.setOnClickListener {
            sendIntent(1)
        }
        val subjectThree = binding.tvHistory
        subjectThree.setOnClickListener{
            sendIntent(2)
        }
        ...


    }
    private fun sendIntent(passedVariable: Int) {
        val intent = Intent(this, SubjectPage::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("subject", passedVariable)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

...
```

At present I have errors from Intent asking to create a function, same with finish().

Having looked through several tutorials I can't seem to see whether it's possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`finish()` is actually called on activity so you can use `requireActivity()` get hold of the hosting activity of your fragment & instead of using `this` in Intent params you can use `requireContext()`

Example:

```
private fun sendIntent(passedVariable: Int) {
        val intent = Intent(requireContext(), MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("subject", passedVariable)
        startActivity(intent)
        requireActivity().finish()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as you started to use fragments you can avoid to start another activity.
Use childFragmentManager and just create for your quiz another fragment.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getChildFragmentManager()